# What is the meaning of `16 longs` and `110 words`, when reads the bits from a file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, bit

I'm trying to read `PUD` file format, that belong to the `warcraft 2` game map.

In the explanation of file structure, there is small phrases I don't understand it.

**What is this mean** (`16 longs`, `110 words`) **?**

**Here is an example**

> 16 longs -------> Units and buildings allowed. (16 players)

```
units bit order:
        0000000000000000000000000000000x        bit0:  footman/grunt
        000000000000000000000000000000x0        bit1:  peasant/peon
        00000000000000000000000000000x00        bit2:  ballista/catapult
        0000000000000000000000000000x000        bit3:  knight/ogre
        000000000000000000000000000x0000        bit4:  archer/axe thrower
        00000000000000000000000000x00000        bit5:  mage/death knights
        0000000000000000000000000x000000        bit6:  tanker
        000000000000000000000000x0000000        bit7:  destroyer
        00000000000000000000000x00000000        bit8:  transport
        0000000000000000000000x000000000        bit9:  battleship/juggernault
        000000000000000000000x0000000000        bit10: submarine/turtle
        00000000000000000000x00000000000        bit11: flying machine/balloon
        0000000000000000000x000000000000        bit12: gryphon/dragon
        000000000000000000x0000000000000        bit13: unused/unused
        00000000000000000x00000000000000        bit14: demo. squad/sapper
        0000000000000000x000000000000000        bit15: aviary/roost
        000000000000000x0000000000000000        bit16: farm
        00000000000000x00000000000000000        bit17: barracks
        0000000000000x000000000000000000        bit18: lumber mill
        000000000000x0000000000000000000        bit19: stables/mound
        00000000000x00000000000000000000        bit20: mage tower/temple
        0000000000x000000000000000000000        bit21: foundry
        000000000x0000000000000000000000        bit22: refinery
        00000000x00000000000000000000000        bit23: inventor/alchemist
        0000000x000000000000000000000000        bit24: church/altar storms
        000000x0000000000000000000000000        bit25: tower
        00000x00000000000000000000000000        bit26: town hall/great hall
        0000x000000000000000000000000000        bit27: keep/stronghold
        000x0000000000000000000000000000        bit28: castle/fortress
        00x00000000000000000000000000000        bit29: blacksmith
        0x000000000000000000000000000000        bit30: shipyard
        x0000000000000000000000000000000        bit31: unused
```

Is this mean `16 longs` = `16*4Bytes = 64` or `16*32Bits = 512` or other.
Also the same thing with `110 words`.

Comment: How does it matter if you read n bytes or n*8 bits? You will find, however, that you can't read single bits, unless those data come via a serial interface and your software supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're referring to C types on a particular architecture. In C, `long` is a type of variable. Its size varies as a function of the compiler, but in this case it's a 32-bit value. Words are processor words, which are typically 32 bits in modern parlance. However, Warcraft 2 was written a long time ago and runs on 16-bit machines. As Sean pointed out in a comment, words are 16 bits in this context.

To answer the question in the comment:

16 longs = 16 * 32 bits = 512 bits = 64 bytes.

110 words = 110 * 16 bits = 1760 bits = 220 bytes.

Comment: Some googling led me to this: http://cade.datamax.bg/war2x/pudspec.html so if it's correct then a long refers to 4 bytes and a word 2 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and the article link which in comment is what I following, but I want a direct answer please `16 longs` = ?, and `110 Words` = ?, and I know the word = 16bit and long = 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've never known "16 longs, 110 words" to have any particular meaning other than long being 64 bit numbers, and words being 32 bit data.  I would perform some experiments and see what values are contained in the first 16 8-byte chunks and then 110 4-byte chunks to see if values are relatively consistent.

If by looking at the word values, you see one bit on like in your table above, then presumably you're reading it correctly.  However, generally speaking, there's no way to know for sure if you're right for these sorts of things, only ways to know if you're wrong.

**Edit:**  Of course, the sizes have changed over the years and "long" may be 4 bytes, not 8.  Likewise words would be 2 bytes, not 4.

Comment: If "long" is different to "word", then I expect they are using the naming conventions adopted in the 16-bit era.  8 bits = 1 byte, 16 bits = 1 word, 32 bits = 1 longword (or double word) and 64 bits is 1 quadword.